# How do I make root user write to daily laravel log file?

Tags: php, laravel-5, file-permissions

I have a Laravel 5.4 project using the daily laravel log format. (A daily log file is created)

I also have a supervisor running `php artisan queue:work` artisan command and is not able to wrote to the daily log file. This is because it is the `root` user. However, the web server can write to the log file.

I tried to run the following commands:

```
sudo chmod -R gu+w storage
sudo chmod -R guo+w storage
sudo chown -R root:www-data app/storage
```

I have discovered the root user is not able to write to the log file as it is created as below;

`-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  12325 May 12 01:30 laravel-2017-05-12.log`

The format below would work but needs me to keep on running `sudo chmod -R 777 storage` which is a security concern.

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu   www-data 111254 May 11 20:55 laravel-2017-05-11.log`

How can I solve this, anyone?